# Typescript React; How to give type to JSS classes object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, jss

My react code:

```
import React from 'react';
import withStyles from "react-jss";

const styles = {
      box: {
          border: "2px solid #000"
      }
  };

interface ComponentProps {}

class Welcome extends React.Component<ComponentProps> {
    render() {
      const {classes, children} = this.props;
      return(<div className={classes.box}></div>);
    }
  }

  export default withStyles(styles)(Welcome);
```

In this `const {classes, children} = this.props;` is showing this error at `classes`:

```
Property 'classes' does not exist on type 'Readonly<ComponentProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)
```

Only way to get rid of this error seems to be doing this;

```
interface ComponentProps {
    classes:any
  }
```

But using `any` is semantically wrong. What type should I give to `classes`, or is this not how jss is used in typescript-react?

(JSS how to use with TS: [github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/master/docs/react-jss-ts.md](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/master/docs/react-jss-ts.md) (only functional component))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `withStyles`, which comes from material ui.  Material UI has `CSSProperties`, which is what you need.

```
import { CSSProperties } from "@material-ui/styles";

interface ComponentProps {
  classes: CSSProperties;
}
```

For a non-MUI solution, check out [CSSType](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype):

```
import CSS from "csstype";

interface ComponentProps {
  classes: { [key: string]: CSS };
}
```

Comment: No, thats not the case. I'm using JSS (https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/). And here: https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/master/docs/react-jss-ts.md , they've explained how to use it with TS. Sadly, I cant find anything for a class component.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for `class Welcome extends React.Component<{ [key: string]: CSS }>` (with `CSS` coming from `csstype`)?